# can aws load balancers be configured to minimize latency by keeping microservice traffic within an availability zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm designing an application to be hosted across 3 availablility zones (AZs) in a single AWS region. The application is composed of several microservices.

When the application serves a web request from the Internet, I'd like the initial request to be load balanced across all AZs. But when the web server makes further microservice calls, I'd like the load balancer to prefer the same AZ as the initial request, to avoid the latency incurred crossing AZs. I'd also like the load balancer to recognize unhealthy instances and route across AZs if needed.

Is such a configuration possible in AWS?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Explicitly configuring intra availability zone  (In another words, with-in same AZ) routing is not supported.

AS @Michael-sqlbot commented:

> By default, a classic ELB is in an intra-AZ mode -- but only on the
>   back side. On the front-side (DNS level), there's no control over which balancer
>   node gets the request. The web server calling a microservice will hit
>   a classic balancer node in a random AZ, which would then send the
>   request to a back-end in the same AZ if cross-AZ is disabled.

2."unhealthy    instances and route across AZs if needed" is how ELB by default    works.

Here is AWS tutorial on [how ELB works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html).

One of the reason they cited for this behavior is interesting:

> For environments where clients cache DNS lookups, incoming requests
>   might favor one of the Availability Zones. Using cross-zone load
>   balancing, this imbalance in the request load is spread across all
>   available instances in the region, reducing the impact of misbehaving
>   clients.

Comment: Point 1 is contradicted by the rest of your answer.  Please explain.  "Inter-availability-zone" means "from one availability zone to another," which of course *is* supported.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I meant "intra-AZ in other words, with-in same availability zone", corrected the mistake.

Comment: Sort of.  From your link: "Cross-zone load balancing is always enabled for an Application Load Balancer and is **disabled by default** for a Classic Load Balancer."  By default, a classic ELB is in an intra-AZ mode -- but only on the back side.  On the front-side, there's no control over which balancer node gets the request, so you're partially correct. Exactly half-right, even: in the circumstances of this question, the web server calling a microservice will hit a classic balancer node in a random AZ, which would then send the request to a back-end in the same AZ if cross-AZ is disabled.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No, my understanding, there is no intra-AZ mode, from documentation "For example, suppose that you have 10 instances in Availability Zone us-west-2a and 2 instances in us-west-2b. If cross-zone load balancing is disabled, the requests are distributed evenly between us-west-2a and us-west-2b. As a result, the 2 instances in us-west-2b serve the same amount of traffic as the 10 instances in us-west-2a. However, if cross-zone load balancing is enabled, the load balancer distributes incoming requests evenly across all 12 instances."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Based on above notes, my understanding is, corss-zone load balancing switch is literally to say "distribute across zone" vs "distribute across all isntances in all zone"

Comment: I see where the confusion comes from.  If cross-AZ is disabled, 50% of the traffic goes to Zone A and 50% of the traffic goes to Zone B.  But the fundamental reason for that is that approximately 50% of traffic initially arrives at a balancer node in each A/Z via round robin DNS, and the balancer nodes consider only instances in their own A/Z.  When "cross-zone" is disabled, the balancer nodes only route traffic intra-A/Z.  When cross-zone is enabled, balancer nodes are free to route traffic inter-A/Z for more even distribution.

Comment: "and the balancer nodes consider only instances in their own A/Z." can you provide any documentation for this point? I was searching for it before posting my answer.

Comment: It's at your link, but thoroughly understanding what the documentation is telling you requires some low level hands-on expertise.    *"If cross-zone load balancing is disabled, the requests are distributed evenly between us-west-2a and us-west-2b*" **this part happens because requests into the balancers are routed there by round-robin DNS**, which is the reason why *"where clients cache DNS lookups, incoming requests might favor one of the Availability Zones"* leading to a traffic imbalance... **because** ELB nodes with cross-zone disabled do not send requests to instances outside their AZ.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot now your second comment & overall theory make sense,  will update the answer. I agree with your statement about low level hands-on. Just started with ELB for one of my experimental work.

Answer (score -1):

I need to understand a bit more about your services.

Are you services stateful or stateless?

If they are stateful services, you better enable stickiness on your load balancer, so that future requests can be routed back to the same server.

If they are stateless services, you shouldn't be bothered about where the request is routed as it's against the design principles of being stateless.

Could you provide more information on why do you want to route your request to the same availablity zone?

Comment: The question says *to avoid the latency incurred crossing AZs*.